# How can I restructure `if` and `else` statements in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

I have two (and sometimes) three variables which determine if I should run a specific code. The problem is that any of them can be true or false and sometimes this leads to messy codes.

For three variables, there are 8 possible scenarios that I have to check. Like this:

```
if($var_a && $var_b && $var_c) {
   // Do this (A)
} else if(!$var_a && $var_b && $var_c) {
   // Do this (B)
} else if($var_a && !$var_b && $var_c) {
   // Do this (C)
} else if(!$var_a && !$var_b && $var_C) {
  // Do this (D)
}
... and so on.
```

Is there any way to use nesting and make this code less messy? It gets confusing at times to keep track of so many possibilities.

It might be easier to understand what I am saying with an example of two variables.

```
if($var_a && $var_b) {
  // Do this (A)
} else if($var_a && !$var_b) {
  // Do this (B)
} else if(!$var_a && $var_b) {
  // Do this (C)
}
```

Is there any way to combine these conditions together so that I don't have to use so many `&&` and `if else` conditions? This will make things less confusing for me when I have to deal with three (may be more) variables.

Comment: Is `Do this` the same for several of the `if` and `else` cases?  If not, then there may not be any way to much improve upon what you already have.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `Do this` is different for all cases. :)

Comment: Conditional permutations? Interesting problem. Are all of your do this (A-H) calls different, if so, what's different about them? It seems like an odd situation to be in if all of the calls are very different.

Comment: I would apply in your case the Object Calisthenics principle, on this. For that, I'll use object for all of you variable and put them on ValueObjects to handle all the cases.

Comment: @GrecoJonathan I was also thinking something similar. Could you please provide some pseudocode to guide me?

Comment: @RealNoob Using the Andrii Filenko's answer I'll dot something like this https://gist.github.com/jonathangreco/fa822fcb3d85085a16ccb1efa026866e

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you should try something like [lookup map](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/switch-case-if-else-or-a-lookup-map-a-study-case-de1c801d944) with [bitwise map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators), in your case, it can be something like this:

```
$bitOne = $var_a ? 1 : 0;
$bitTwo = $var_b ? 2 : 0;
$bitThree = $var_c ? 4 : 0;
$resultKey = $bitOne | $bitTwo | $bitThree;

$map = [
    7 => function() { return 'All are true'; },
    3 => function() { return 'var_a and var_b are true'; },
    6 => function() { return 'var_b and var_c are true'; },
    // and so on
];

$result = $map[$resultKey];
```

Comment: What if the different cases (the closures you have) require various data, you would have to pass in all the data into the scope of these methods.

Comment: You would need an $options array which you could pass in with function($options...) or something like that @NigelRen

Comment: @NigelRen you can pass as an argument as Shardj said, or you can pass it via use ($variable) language construct

Comment: Passing this data and maintaining context(usually the variable names) adds more complexity to this solution.  This seems more like an academic exercise than a real world coding example (IMHO).

Comment: @NigelRen What about this ? https://gist.github.com/jonathangreco/fa822fcb3d85085a16ccb1efa026866e

Comment: @GrecoJonathan Well - you have managed to add a class for each line of code - you've increased the lines by at least 20+ times (and split it over several files).  You also seem to assume that the same process for each variable is associated with each class rather than potentially being something totally independent - `$a->doStuff(); $b->doOtherStuff(); $a->toStuffWithB($b);`.  Also does `toStuffWithB` involve creating a dependency between these two classes - which isn't good OO.

Answer (score 0):

If you extract the common variable (or an arbitrary choice in this case), you can produce a more layered approach, although the combinations will still mount up and it looks more code, it should be clearer...

```
if($var_a) {
    if(!$var_b) {
        // $var_a && !$var_b
    }
    else {
        // $var_a && $var_b
    }
} 
else {
    if($var_b) {
        // !$var_a && $var_b
    }
}
```

Comment: IMO it still messy

Comment: @GrecoJonathan, would you like to add some reason for this - always interested to see what people think can be done.

Comment: As my other comment suggest, I'll put those vars into objects (string object for example) instead of testing the variable directly, and put those objects into ValueObject with the correct rules that should applies. valueObject and Object Calisthenics principle should clarify the whole thing, imo

Comment: Thanks @NigelRen :). I also wanted to use this technique but it will still get messy when I have three variable or 4 variables.

Comment: @GrecoJonathan so in fact you would add loads more code for the same case.  Just had a read of some of the principle you talk of and (IMHO) it's not good - early returns instead of `else` - so you would need multiple methods instead of multiple `elses` - it will be interesting to see you apply the principles to this problem and I look forward to your answer.

Comment: when it comes to a code with a huge cyclomatic complexity, add "loads" of code to clarify this and make easy to add a new case is IMHO the best way to do this. Plus, we don't know what the rules are, and the complexity of those rules

Comment: @GrecoJonathan quoting cyclomatic complexity is not a real world how people work, it's (IMHO) a guide to help coding and not a golden rule to work with.